# My hadoop code never enters a test on key value

Tags: java, hadoop

I wrote a mapreduce program and I would like to test the key value of the combiner.

Here is the code of the combiner :

```
public static class FlowStats_Combiner extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

     public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

         String test = key.toString().trim();

         if ((test=="srcPort")||(test=="dstPort")||(test=="srcAddr")||(test=="dstAddr")){

             StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
             for (Text value:values){
                 builder.append(value.toString());
                 builder.append('|');
             }

               context.write(key, new Text(builder.toString()));
         }


         if ((test=="Packet")||(test=="Byte")||(test=="Flow")){
             int sum = 0;
             for (Text value : values){
                 sum += Integer.valueOf(value.toString());
             }
               context.write(key, new Text(Integer.toString(sum)));
         }                       
     }
}
```

The program never enters the IF test. Would you have an idea of what is wrong ?
thank you.
Winston.

Comment: If you are using an IDE then I think it should point what Reimeus said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String#equals` to compare `Strings`. The `==` operator compares Object references. The `Strings` returned from the [`trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method are different objects to the String literals that you are comparing against so the `if` statement blocks are never entered

```
if (test.equals("srcPort") || 
    test.equals("dstPort")|| 
    test.equals("srcAddr") || 
    test.equals("dstAddr")) {
```

To avoid `NPE` you could use

```
if ("srcPort".equals(test) || 
    "dstPort".equals(test)|| 
    "srcAddr".equals(test) || 
    "dstAddr".equals(test)) {
```